# How can I use validation groups for DTOs in a NestJS controller?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, class-validator, class-transformer

I want to use validation groups in my DTO and use them in my controller. Does anyone know how you can use/pass validation groups to the controller or have the `request.user` automatically pass it to the controller?

create-user.dto.ts

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty({
    groups: ["admin"],
  })
  role: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}
```

users.controller.ts

```
@Controller('users')
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const result = await this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`@IsNotEmpty` and `@IsEmail` decorators are coming from the `class-validator` library, so you should use `ValidationPipe`

Nest JS docs about validation: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Updated **users.controller.ts**:

```js
@Controller('users')
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ groups: ["admin"] }))
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const result = await this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually have the validation pipe on globally, the issue is that adding the pipe like you mentioned above works if I hard code the group, but I want to validate based on the request user's group.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my draft for this one. As there are not much information around how to dynamicly set validation group.

First of all, create method generateGroups, inside the DTO. Put corresponding logic to fill validation groups. In my example I am using field name as group.

```
enum APP_SETTING {
    MAINTENANCE_MODE = "maintenance-mode",
    RECONNECTION_DELAY = "reconnection-delay"
}

export class EditSettingDto {
    protected readonly generateGroups? = () => {
        const groups = [];
        if (Object.values(APP_SETTING).includes(this.name)) {
            groups.push(this.name);
        }
        return groups;
    };

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEnum(APP_SETTING, { always: true })
    name: APP_SETTING;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsBoolean({ groups: [APP_SETTING.MAINTENANCE_MODE] })
    @IsInt({ groups: [APP_SETTING.RECONNECTION_DELAY] })
    value: any;
}
```

Afterwards you may have custom validation pipe which should have execution priority over global pipe. In my case I compose ValidationPipe with custom transform logic.

Check for existance of generateGroups method in the DTO and collect all groups by calling it and passing groups to the ValidationPipe instance. Run validationPipe.transform with input arguments. That's it!

```
export class CustomValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private readonly options?: ValidationPipeOptions) {}

    transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<any> {
        const { metatype } = metadata;

        const instance = plainToInstance(metatype, value);

        let groups: string[] = [];
        if (typeof instance.generateGroups === "function") {
            groups = instance.generateGroups();
        }

        const validationPipe = new ValidationPipe({
            ...this.options,
            groups
        });

        return validationPipe.transform(value, metadata);
    }
}
```

Main.ts

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
        new CustomValidationPipe({
            whitelist: true
        })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this will do the trick for me.
My ideal use case still won't work though, I want to have a URL `@Param` used to validate the groups for my `@query` DTO, do you know a way I can achieve that?